How do I run Safe wallet and 4337 run on our L3 and How can I use `@safe-global/relay-kit` sdk on it to run init and other functions
I have already deployed AA contracts like entrypoint/aymaster & Safe and Safe4337Module contract. Now I want to use @safe-global/relay-kit sdk by providing my chains' RPC and bundler URL. Is there any process or steps mentioned to follow?

You will have to configure and deploy your own Safe Transaction Service,  and then initialize the Safe{Core} SDK API Kit with the URL of your own service.
You can find more info on the Safe Transaction Service here, and more about how to use the 4337 module for your safe here.
Let me know if you need any other info on how to integrate the SDK and infrastructure. Hope it helps; Best, Louis

thanks for the response, I deep dived into the core setup code to make 4337 transactions, and getting this issue: Invalid UserOp signature or paymaster signature
Any idea what maybe the reasons? or should I provide more context?

Without more context it will difficult to provide a precise answer. This error generally means that there was an error verifying the signatures needed for the relay call Are you sure you generated them the correct way? More info on that here: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/signatures Feel free also to open a new question on stackexchange to provide additional info about the problem.
